# Get historic amount corresponding to a specific amount today

Tags: inflation

Are there any site out there that can give the equivalent value of a specific amount today.

For instance, $20 today would be the same as $5 dollars twenty years ago.

Comment: Swedish calculator would be preferred, but I assumed that it would be  easier to find a US one.

Comment: And, of course, there's always wolframalpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sweden+inflation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also try Measuring Worth: http://www.measuringworth.com/calculators/index.php

Their calculators do a great job with purchasing power questions. They also have calculators available for same with Yen and GBP.

Comment: Ah, good old MeasuringWorth. I worked on that website back when it was part of EH.Net. There's a lot of nice background information there on why you'd want to make a comparison using one series or another, as well.

Answer (score 2):

[The Inflation Calculator](http://www.westegg.com/inflation/), of course. I trust the dollars are US, as I saw $ symbol, this calculator is US only.